# Annotate insertions/deletions in listings

Tags: listings

I'd like to annotate some lines in my `lstlisting` environment as having been added or deleted. To do this I'd like to put a `(+)` or `(-)` symbol next to the line numbers, like this:

```
1       function foo {
2(-)      printf 'Hello whirled\n';
3(+)      printf 'Hello world\n';
4       }
```

Is there a nice way to do this using the `listings` package? So far I've just been doing it using manual spacing hacks.

Here's a little starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left,escapechar=",numbersep=8mm]
function foo {
"\rlap{\hspace{-7mm}\tt (-)}"  printf 'Hello whirled\n';
"\rlap{\hspace{-7mm}\tt (+)}"  printf 'Hello world\n';
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "nice way"? Would you like to specify the list of added/deleted lines at the beginning (as an option) instead of marking them manually?

Comment: Good point. I'm happy to mark the lines manually, though also happy to mark them at the top if that aids implementation. I just don't like the hacky `\hspace` stuff, it's not very principled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible approaches in order to automatically print (-) or (+) after the line number, where needed:

1. Manually mark lines and do some parsing.
2. Specify added/deleted lines at the beginning of the `lstlisting` environment.

Approach 1 seems too complicated. Approach 2, although less user-friendly, appears easier to set up, especially if you create two new `listings` keys for specifying the lists of added/deleted lines.

Here is an implementation of Approach 2. It's probably not very clever in terms of algorithmic complexity, but it seems to do the trick. It's compatible with both `numbers=left` and `numbers=right`. You can use the `pgffor` syntax (e.g. `1,...,4,7`) for the lists of added/deleted lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter

% define a new listings key for specifying a list of added lines
\newcommand\listofaddedlines@jw{}
\lst@Key{addedlines}\relax{%
  \edef\listofaddedlines@jw{#1}%
}

% define a new listings key for specifying a list of deleted lines
\newcommand\listofdeletedlines@jw{}
\lst@Key{deletedlines}\relax{%
  \edef\listofdeletedlines@jw{#1}%
}

% redefiniion of the numbers key
% (I only inserted my \printdeloraddsign@jw in two places)
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \let\lst@PlaceNumber\@empty
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none&\\%
     left&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber\printdeloraddsign@jw}\kern\lst@numbersep}}\\%
     right&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\printdeloraddsign@jw}}%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}

% auxiliary switch (used in \printdeloraddsign@jw)
\newif\ifaddordel@jw@

% macro for printing (+) or (-) or a hphantom equivalent
\newcommand\printdeloraddsign@jw{%
  \foreach \linenum in \listofaddedlines@jw{%
    \ifnum\thelstnumber=\linenum\relax%
      {\ttfamily(+)}%
      \global\addordel@jw@true%
    \fi
  }%
  \foreach \linenum in \listofdeletedlines@jw{%
    \ifnum\thelstnumber=\linenum\relax%
      {\ttfamily(-)}%
      \global\addordel@jw@true%
    \fi
  }%
  \ifaddordel@jw@\else
    \hphantom{\ttfamily(-)}%
  \fi
      \global\addordel@jw@false%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left,deletedlines=2,addedlines=3]
function foo {
  printf 'Hello whirled\n';
  printf 'Hello world\n';
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=right,deletedlines={2,...,4},addedlines=5]
function foo {
  printf 'Hello whirled\n';
  \* rubbish *\
  \* more rubbish *\
  printf 'Hello world\n';
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome enough to accept `:p` or is something missing?

Comment: Just wanted to maximise the visibility of this question by holding off on accepting for a little while. Just so you get all the up votes you deserve!

Comment: @JohnWickerson It looks like I didn't deserve that many upvotes `;...(` Oh well...

Comment: I know! Pah. Well, I thought your answer was super Jubobs :)